# Jquery Ajax call with promise

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with validation code that requires an Ajax call to a database, the return value from which must be handled before the form is submitted. I've tried using promises as below but am obviously misundersanding the syntax. The return values are still in the required order. Your help will be greatly valued.

The key parts of the code are:

```
// checks form submission
$('#ml_doaction').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isOK = true;
  $('form#managelists :input').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    switch(id)
    {
      case 'maillist':
        checkNewListName(id).then(function(data) {
        if(data === false) {
          isOK = false;
        }
      });
      break;

      // etc ....
      }
  });

  if(isOK === true) {
    // submit form
    $('form#managelists').submit();
  }
});

function checkNewListName(id)
{
  var listVal = $('#' + id).val();
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    data:{'checklistexists': listVal},
    url:'/php/ajax/validation-ajax.php',
    success:function(response){
      if(response == 'listexists') {
        dfd.resolve(false);
      }
      else {
        dfd.resolve(true);
      }
    }
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: FYI `$.ajax` returns a promise.

Comment: The `switch` statement in your code sample is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @Tomalak: In what way is it invalid, please?

Comment: It is. Try it. The JS compiler will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ah, yes.A case statement would be good! Code example updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's clean up your `checkNewListName()` function. It's the purpose of that function to take a list name and return `true` if the  given list exists on the server, and `false` otherwise.

The server takes a moment to figure this out, so we can ask the question, and the answer will arrive some time later. This can be solved through promises, as you did, but when we take into account that jQuery Ajax requests *already are* promises, we can make the function much simpler (and give it a better name - my convention is, functions that return promises are called `somethingAsync`):

```
function checkListNameExistsAsync(listName) {
  return $.post('/php/ajax/validation-ajax.php', {
    checklistexists: listName
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response == 'listexists';
    });
  });
}
```

This takes a list name and returns a promise for `true` or `false`. It has no DOM dependency, so we can test it in the console:

```
checkListNameExistsAsync('foobar').then(function (exists) {
  console.log(exists);
});
```

which will probably log `false`.

With that out of the way, we can call this in a loop and get a bunch of promises.

First step, getting all the list names we want to check (this gives an array of strings):

```
var allListNames = $('form#managelists :input').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).toArray();
```

Second step, requesting checks for all of them (this gives an array of promises for Boolean values):

```
var allChecks = allListNames.map(checkNewListNameAsync);
```

Third, we need to wait until all these promises have settled. This can be done through `Promoise.all()`, or with jQuery's own utility function, `$.when()`:

```
var overallResult = $.when.apply($, allChecks);
```

`overallResult` is another promise, which resolves when all the input promises have resolved. So we can attach a `.then` handler, which will receive the results of all input promises in its `arguments`. If any argument is equal to `true`, at least one of the lists already exists:

```
overallResult.then(function () {
  if (Array.from(arguments).includes(true)) {
    alert("At least one list already exists!");
  } else {
    $('form#managelists').submit();
  }
});
```

The arguments will be in the same order as the input list (`allListNames`), so you can use that to figure out which list exists.

Don't forget to attach a `.fail()` handler to `overallResult`, to catch any errors.

Comment: P.S.: Since the information whether a list name exists is something we *read from* the server, it should be done a GET request, really. POST requests are meant to *write to* the server. Which is not what is happening in this case, so I would recommend to change that.

Comment: This is a much better tutorial than I've seen elsewhere online. Very many thanks for explaining how to combine multiple promises. Point about GET taken!

Comment: Another consideration is to match up your API operations and your JS function names. I didn't think of that when I wrote the answer, but if your API operation (currently implemented as a URL parameter) is `checkListExists`, then the JS function should probably also be called `checkListExists` (+ the `Async` suffix, if you subscribe to my convention).

Comment: Also, there was a bug in my answer, compare [revision #2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53050686/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

The `then()` callback gets executed if the AJAX is successful. Check the `isOK` flag (client side validation) and ensure the result from the AJAX call is valid (server side validation). If both pass, do the form submission.

```
// checks form submission
$('#ml_doaction').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isOK = true;
  $('form#managelists :input').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    switch(id)
    {
      checkNewListName(id).then(function(data) {
        if(isOK && data !== false) {
          // submit form
          $('form#managelists').submit();
        }
      });
      break;

      // etc ....
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: @data: The isOK variable is being set by other tests in the switch block with a test at the end, so I can't ignore it as you suggest. Would you say more about "until the promise is complete"? When will this be?

Comment: @magnol - When the promise is complete, the `then` function is called -  `checkNewListName(id).then(function(data) { /* code in here*/ }` - this does not happen until the ajax has completed. I've updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Many thanks.This is a great help. Your code requires that the Ajax call will _always_ return after the other tests in the switch block have been completed. This seems reasonable, as none include other Ajax calls, but can one bank on it?

Comment: The Ajax will return after your other checks. In fact, it won't even start executing until the switch statement has excited. JavaScript doesn't know how to "switch contexts". The `$.ajax()` call queues up something to be executed after the currently executing code has finished.